# When name spacing models. Should the containing folder's name be in plural form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

when name spacing models. should the containing folder's name be in plural form?

i.e. `models/users/comment.rb` or `models/user/comment.rb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to exactly match the namespace, so making the namespace singular means a singular for the folder.

I use singular, and I think that's common.  After all, the path to the model is about one model, not the collection.  Plural is used in Rails for a collection, like an array variable or a database table name.  Controllers use plural, I think because of the REST convention.  Everything else is singular.

Answer (score 1):

Plural form works too, but i think it's good practice to use the singular form.

After all, models are singular by default..

```
rails g model User/Comment
```

And after migrating, access it with:

```
User::Comment
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply load that like : [Namespaced models](http://m.onkey.org/namespaced-models)

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  # Your existing stuff

  config.load_paths << "#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/models/pets"
end
```

Comment: I don't think this is necessary for Rails 3+